# file pointer is changing to NULL when fread last line in c

Tags: c, file, pointers, null, binary

I have a binary file with 5 long ints, everything working as expected but when I read the last item in the file the file pointer return NULL from func2 and int the end of func2 filepointer is still not null but when im back to func1 I see it became naull,can you please help me understand why?
this is the 2 functions:

```
long int * func1(char * filename, int numOflogInts)
{
    long int numbers[5];
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename,"rb");
    for (int i = 0; i < numOflogInts; i++) {
        numbers[i] = func2(fp, i);
    }
    return numbers;
    fclose(fp);
}

long int func2(FILE * fp, int place)
{
    long int num;
    fseek(fp, sizeof(long int) * place, SEEK_SET);//skip to the place
    fread(&num, sizeof(long int), 1, fp);
    return num;
}
```

Comment: you're returning the address of the local variable `numbers`, which goes out of scope when the function ends. Also, `fclose(fp)` will never be reached, once you `return` that's it, nothing gets executed in the function after that.

Comment: this is not the issue, the issue is why my file pointer is becoming null

Comment: presumably you're reading that value on return, which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), meaning anything can happen. a [mre] would be most helpful. You should also check the file successfully opens before trying to read from it.

Comment: I see no direct reason in the code provided why `fp` would suddenly become NULL (unless it is from the start). The error is probably in code not shown, perhaps some other UB. .. unless I'm missing it of course.

Comment: And just what is `numOflogInts`? If it has a value > 5, then you have a buffer overflow which means memory corruption and undefined behavior. Things incorrectly changing under such conditions is fair game. And @yano's points may be different issues, but they are important too.

Comment: If `numOflogInts` is 6, the assignment `numbers[i] = func2(...` will overwrite whatever is next in memory after `numbers` array and there is a good chance that you may hit `fp` there.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of mistakes:

- You're returning the address of an array that's need allocated on the stack. Using it after this leads to undefined behavior.
- Also in `func1` you've returned, *then* closed the file pointer. But because of the return, this `fclose` call is unreachable.
- You've got a constant `5`, rather than using `numOflogInts` to determine the size of your array. Your loop suggests this is not the right thing to do.

To address the first issue, *dynamically* allocate your array. To fix the second, close the file before returning.

```
long int * func1(char * filename, int numOflogInts)
{
    long int *numbers = malloc(sizeof(long int) * numOflogInts);
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename,"rb");
    for (int i = 0; i < numOflogInts; i++) {
        numbers[i] = func2(fp, i);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return numbers;
}
```

Of course, you also want to check for errors in both your memory allocation and in opening the file.